# Extract a custom HTML attribute from a string

Tags: java, regex

I need to extract `data-user_id`numbers from a string

**input string example**

```
 data-user_id="987654" lorem epsem  lorem epsem  lorem epsem  lorem
 data-user_id="123456-6" lorem epsem epsem  lorem epsem
 <img src="abcd.com"/> lorem epsem  data-user_id="123456"
```

**expected output**

987654,123456-6,123456

**Code I have (don't work)**

```
private static String getIdFromLine(String inputLine) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(data-user_id=\"[0-9a-z]*\")");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(inputLine);
    if (m.find()) {
        String src = m.group(2);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have this regex:

```
data-user_id=\"([0-9a-z-]+)\"
```

`group(1)` will contain the desired output.

Your code suffers from more problems; you're *not* looping on the result, instead of `if` you should have `while` loop:

```
while (m.find()) {
    //build the result here
{
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid compiltation of the pattern on each method call, I would write the method like this:

```
private static Pattern DATA_USER_ID_PATTERN = //
        Pattern.compile("data-user_id=\"([0-9a-z-]+)\"");

private static String getIdFromLine(String inputLine) {
    String src = null;
    Matcher m = DATA_USER_ID_PATTERN.matcher(inputLine);
    if (m.find()) {
        src = m.group(1);
    }

    return src;
}
```

If you're sure that no multiple threads will call your method, you can write it like this:

```
private static Matcher DATA_USER_ID_MATCHER = //
        Pattern.compile("data-user_id=\"([0-9a-z-]+)\"").matcher("");

private static String getIdFromLine(String inputLine) {
    String src = null;
    Matcher m = DATA_USER_ID_MATCHER;

    m.reset(inputLine);
    if (m.find()) {
        src = m.group(1);
    }

    return src;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your attempt:

1. your regex expression doesn't match the `-` character (or uppercase letters, in case you need those)
2. you aren't building up your string to return
3. you aren't looping using `while` to get all the matches in a single string

**EDIT** you've now edited your question to have a different input string. It is not clear if you will have multiple matches per line now.

try:

```
private static String getIdFromLine(String inputLine) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("data-user_id=\"([0-9a-zA-Z-]*)\"");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(inputLine);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    while (m.find()) {
        String src = m.group(1);
        sb.append(src + ",");
    }
    int len = sb.length();
    if (len > 0)
        sb.delete(len - 1, len);

    return sb.toString();
}
```